# How do I One Hot encode mixed strings and number cell values in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a datasets in which i need to One hot encode composition mixture of different materials.
The columns of my dataset looks like this:

```
id            Composition 
0             ZrB2 - 5% B4C
1    HfB2 - 15% SiC - 3% WC
2            HfB2 - 15% SiC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lgxk.png)
I need to put it in this format:

```
0)
ZrB2                                 95
HfB2                                  0
SiC                                   0
B4C                                   5
WC                                    0
1)
ZrB2                                  0
HfB2                                  82
SiC                                   15
B4C                                   0
WC                                    3
2)
ZrB2                                  0
HfB2                                  85
SiC                                   15
B4C                                   0
WC                                    0
WB                                    0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EHJv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not *hot encoding* as such but parsing a list of strings into constituent parts

1. each component is delimited by " - "
2. each component is made up of two parts *percentage* and *column name*.  Build re that matches each of these constituent parts
3. from `list`/`dict` comprehension put it into a dataframe
4. complete logic for calculating %age of column where it was not defined

```py
data = ['ZrB2 - 5% B4C', 'HfB2 - 15% SiC - 3% WC', 'HfB2 - 15% SiC']

dfhc = pd.DataFrame({"Composition":data})

# build a list of dict,  where dict is of form {'ZrB2': -1, 'B4C': '5'}
# where no %age,  default to -1 to be calculated later
parse1 = [{tt[1]:tt[0].replace("% ","") if len(tt[0])>0 else -1
          for t in r
           # parse out token and percentage,  exclude empty tuples (default behaviour of re.findall())
          for tt in [x for x in re.findall("([0-9]*[%]?[ ]?)([A-Z,a-z,0-9]*)",t) if x!=("","")]
          }
        # each column is delimited by " - "
        for r in [re.split(" - ",r) for r in dfhc["Composition"].values]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(parse1)
# dtype is important for sum() to work
df = df.astype({c:np.float64 for c in df.columns})

# where %age was not known and defaulted to -1 set it to 100 - sum of other cols
for c in df.columns:
    mask = df[df[c]==-1].index
    df.loc[mask, c] = 100 - df.loc[mask, [cc for cc in df.columns if cc!=c]].sum(axis=1)

print(f"{dfhc.to_string(index=False)}\n\n{df.to_string(index=False)}\n\n{parse1}")
```

**output**

```
            Composition
          ZrB2 - 5% B4C
 HfB2 - 15% SiC - 3% WC
         HfB2 - 15% SiC

 ZrB2  B4C  HfB2   SiC   WC
 95.0  5.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
  NaN  NaN  82.0  15.0  3.0
  NaN  NaN  85.0  15.0  NaN

[{'ZrB2': -1, 'B4C': '5'}, {'HfB2': -1, 'SiC': '15', 'WC': '3'}, {'HfB2': -1, 'SiC': '15'}]
```